# Implementing Chips

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

How do i implement chips in the column of my table, can anyone help? i need to show the results of the types `{{truck.type}}` as chips on the table but currently its just showing as regular words

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="type">Type</th>
    <mat-chip-list><mat-chip><td mat-cell *matCellDef="let truck" class="pr-24">{{truck.type}}</td></mat-chip></mat-chip-list>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: did u  import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips' in app.module.ts

Comment: yes i did import

Comment: Try wrapping the `mat-chip-list` inside `td`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your HTML table doesn't have a proper structure; a table generally has this structure:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In your case, however, it is somewhat difficult to adapt the whole thing to this structure. So instead you might want to reconstruct your template, but you'll also need a little help from CSS:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="type">
  <mat-chip-list class="table">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="cell" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="type">Type</div>
    </div>
    <mat-chip class="row" *matCellDef="let truck of trucks" >
      <div mat-cell class="cell pr-24">{{truck.type}}</div>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</ng-container>
```

```css
.table { display:table; }
.row { display:table-row; }
.cell{ display:table-cell; }
```

P.S. if you give me a working example (here or via stackblitz.com etc.) then I can help you to achieve the desired css look.

Comment: hey mate, its complicated for me to send a stackblitz. but ur code works, i just have to adjust it little, thanks mate.